# Why can't "this.$el" be recognized in my Backbone.js app?

Tags: backbone.js

When I use `this.$el` in my backbone.js app, firebug always tells me `this.$el` is not defined. I have to switch to `$(this.el)` to refer to the jquery element. Is there any difference between these two methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I'm assuming you are referring to the `$el` attribute on `Backbone.View` objects)

I had a similar problem that was because I was using an older version of Backbonethat did not support the [`$el`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-%24el) attribute on `Backbone.View` objects.  Try [upgrading Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#upgrading) to 0.9 or greater.

Comment: I think this is the most possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

`this.$el` is a cached version of `$(this.el)` [check documentationt](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-%24el) it should work in normal situations, never has failed to me. [Backbone it self uses it several times](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1183).

I think you have your problem somewhere else.